# Trying to find libraries with pkg-config on Windows

Tags: windows, rust, pkg-config

Currently I'm trying to build a Rust Cargo but I get stuck at this traceback saying that pkg-config can't find a specific package

```bash
pkg-config --libs --cflags libavutil
```

```
Package libavutil was not found in the pkg-config search path.
Perhaps you should add the directory containing `libavutil.pc'
to the PKG_CONFIG_PATH environment variable
No package 'libavutil' found
```

I tried searching online how to fix this issue but no luck whatsoever, and I think this is the best place to ask for my issue, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Firstly you have to be sure `libavutil` package is installed on your system.

Run this command in terminal. It should be listed in the output.

```
pkg-config --list-all | grep libavutil
```

Then set env `PKG_CONFIG_PATH`.

```
export PKG_CONFIG_PATH=$PKG_CONFIG_PATH:{your_pkgconfig_path}
```

Comment: If `pkg-config --list-all` shows `libavutil`, then you don't need to export `PKG_CONFIG_PATH`

Comment: Which terminal should I use for these commands? I tried using CMD, Anaconda and PowerShell on Windows, but no luck!

Comment: Actually nevermind, I got it to work using Ubuntu, where do I find my PKG_CONFIG_PATH?